# How to count errors?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

I made a script in Javascript (for phantomjs) to automate tests in a website.
I would like to count the errors encountered.
With this script, I get the error : "nbe variable unknown".
I understand that try... catch works in a specific way but I don't know what to do.
How can I modify my script to make it work? 
Thank you

```
var nbe = 0;
var err = 0;

function next_page() {
  page.evaluate(function() {

    try {
      document.querySelector('input[name="cc"]').click();

    } catch (e) {
      nbe++;
      console.log('Error');
      err = 1;
    }


  });


  var k = i + 1 - nbe;
  if (err == 0) console.log('Test ' + k + ' done');
  i++;

  if (i < links.length) setTimeout(handle_page, 1500);
  else {
    console.log('Errors : ' + nbe);
    phantom.exit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
var nbe = 0;
var err = 0;
var errors = [];

function next_page() {
  page.evaluate(function() {

    try {
      document.querySelector('input[name="cc"]').click();

    } catch (e) {
      nbe++;
      console.log('Error');
      err = 1;
      errors.push(e);
    }
  });


  var k = i + 1 - nbe;
  if (err === 0) {
    console.log('Test ' + k + ' done')
  };
  i++;

  if (i < links.length) {
    setTimeout(handle_page, 1500);
  } else {
    for(var j = 0; j < errors.length; j++){
        console.log(errors[j]);
    }
    phantom.exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am affraid that this generate the same error : nbe unknown.
But you think that using only errors as an array will solve the problem?

The fact is with this script, when I do not use the variable "nbe" : "Error" is not displayed and "if (err == 0)" is always true.

Seems that the catch is not properly executed...

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that produces this error?